# I am trying to print error if the field is empty, I am trying the code below but its not working, The array is build of id values of HTML

Tags: javascript

```
function formHasErrors()
{
    let details = ["fullName","address","empNumber"];
    let errorFlag = false
    for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
        let shippingInfoField = document.getElementById(details[i])
        if (!fieldHasInput(shippingInfoField)) {
            document.getElementById(details[i]);
            if (!errorFlag) {
                shippingInfoField.focus();
                shippingInfoField.select();
            }
            // Returns true that the form has errors.
            errorFlag = true;
        }
    }
    //  Code above here!
    return errorFlag;
}
```

I tried to print error using javascript, the array is formed of id value of HTML for which I want to print error if the field is empty but code is not working, how to proceed?

Comment: I don't see anyplace where you are trying to print something.

Comment: not a good approach. your `errorFlag` will always be true after the first condition fail and will never go into the `shippingInfoField.focus()...` lines, what are you trying?..where's `fieldHasInput` method?